# Mark and check a process if it's completed or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm not sure how to write this line.  What I'm looking to do is write one statement that is only done once and upon completion marks itself to not be done again(To avoid a constant loop) for something like a day time and night time.

What I think needs to be written:

```
    if ([nightTime timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0 && "check if already reset or not"){
        // The following process has to be done, but only once

        // reset dayTime (for tomorrow)

        // stop the current NSTimer

        // recreate a new NSTimer for nightTime        

   }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I should use?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi,<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You need a call back method. I guess. If you do not know when your expected state (condition to be checked) is unknown or cannot be determined by you. If you know when it will comes to that situation then better have a flag and mark it as `yes` or `no`. Hope this may give you a overview. Let me know if need further.

Answer (score 0):

Take one flag iIsProcessDone

```
if ([nightTime timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0 && !iIsProcessDone){

        iIsProcessDone = YES;

        // The following process has to be done, but only once

        // reset dayTime (for tomorrow)

        // stop the current NSTimer

        // recreate a new NSTimer for nightTime        

   }
```

And reset it when you want to call this process again.